# Converting an SQLlite database to PostgreSQL, but the database is still not working

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

My original SQLite database begins like this:

```
#PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;

#BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

Then a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field:

```
CREATE TABLE inputs 
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
  name TEXT, 
  inputid INT, 
  connectionid INT, 
  type INT, 
  posx DOUBLE, 
  posy DOUBLE
);
```

I tried to change  the `AUTO_INCREMENT`

I tried this:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE inputs
(
  id SERIAL,
  name TEXT, 
  inputid INT, 
  connectionid INT, 
  type INT, 
  posx DOUBLE, 
  posy DOUBLE
);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: What error do you run into?

Comment: "Not working" is an insufficient problem description.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Just as an aside, if you **don't** include DDL within a transaction, it is autocommittted anyway - both in SQLite and PostgreSQL - just like DML transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `serial` doesn't imply that the column is also a primary (or unique) key. And in modern Postgres versions, an `identity` column is [preferred](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) over `serial`

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) there is no data type `double` - it's called `double precision`

So the table definition should be:

```
create table inputs
(
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  name text, 
  inputid int, 
  connectionid int, 
  type int, 
  posx double precision, 
  posy double precision
);
```

Comment: Also working:CREATE TABLE inputs (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT, inputid INT, connectionid INT, type INT, posx double precision, posy double precision);
INSERT INTO inputs (id, name, inputid, connectionid, type, posx, posy) VALUES (42, 'Unknown', 1, 23, 0, 276.0, 226.316);
INSERT INTO inputs (id, name, inputid, connectionid, type, posx, posy) VALUES (43, 'WEJ', 1, 51, 4, 726.159, 384.892);